# Overloading oracle procedure with DATE and VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code that doesn't work.  It compiles, but when called with sysdate as the `parm_value` parameter it throws `PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'P_UPSERT_SDE_DATA' match this call`  If I comment out the varchar2 entry, the overload works as expected with just date and number datatypes.

What is the best way to go about what I'm trying to do, which is accept parameters differing only in parm_values datatype(specifically date and varchar2)?

```
  PROCEDURE P_Upsert_SDE_Data(parm_table_name   GORSDAV.GORSDAV_TABLE_NAME%TYPE,
                              parm_attr_name      GORSDAV.GORSDAV_ATTR_NAME%TYPE,
                              parm_key              GORSDAV.GORSDAV_PK_PARENTTAB%TYPE,
                              parm_user_id        GORSDAV.GORSDAV_USER_ID%TYPE,
                              parm_value            VARCHAR2);
--                            
  PROCEDURE P_Upsert_SDE_Data(parm_table_name   GORSDAV.GORSDAV_TABLE_NAME%TYPE,
                              parm_attr_name      GORSDAV.GORSDAV_ATTR_NAME%TYPE,
                              parm_key              GORSDAV.GORSDAV_PK_PARENTTAB%TYPE,
                              parm_user_id        GORSDAV.GORSDAV_USER_ID%TYPE,
                              parm_value            NUMBER);

  PROCEDURE P_Upsert_SDE_Data(parm_table_name   GORSDAV.GORSDAV_TABLE_NAME%TYPE,
                              parm_attr_name      GORSDAV.GORSDAV_ATTR_NAME%TYPE,
                              parm_key              GORSDAV.GORSDAV_PK_PARENTTAB%TYPE,
                              parm_user_id        GORSDAV.GORSDAV_USER_ID%TYPE,
                              parm_value            DATE);
```

Comment: So, how do you call the procedure?

Comment: `UTL_SDE.p_Upsert_SDE_Data('FRBGRNT','GRANT_END_DATE',var_FRBGRNT_CODE,'BANNER_GAS_SYNS',SYSDATE);`  but i've tried susbstituing `TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyymmdd')` for sysdate.  same issue.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full data types of the `gorsdav` columns and the `var_frb_grnt_code` (?) variable?

Comment: Are these procedures in a nested subprogram (e.g. part of larger plsql block) or part of a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this if one of the others arguments you pass is being implicitly converted; from the call you posted I suspect `var_FRB‌​GRNT_CODE` is a different type and is being converted; e.g. that variable is a number and `GORSDAV.GORSDAV_PK_PARENTTAB` is a string.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#sthref700):

> When trying to determine which subprogram was invoked, if the PL/SQL compiler implicitly converts one parameter to a matching type, then the compiler looks for other parameters that it can implicitly convert to matching types. If there is more than one match, then compile-time error PLS-00307 occurs, as in [Example 8-34](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#CHDICIIG).

Implicit conversion of one of the other arguments makes it look for potential conversions of the others; it's only then that it sees the date and varchar2 versions, which can be implicitly converted to each other. If all of the arguments are of the same type as the table columns used for the formal parameter declarations then it won't look for implicit conversions, and won't be confused by the date/varchar2 versions.

Comment: Exactly right.  I was so concerned about the overloaded variable, I didn't think the ones that were all the same would matter.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get this error, it seems to be that there's a mismatch between the spec declaration and the body declaration somewhere.  Make sure each of your spec declarations match your body declarations exactly.